# Declare sepperate variables from json

Tags: php, json, variables

I have a JSON format as the following:

```
$myresult = '{"promoter_name":[],"country":["Hong Kong"],"download":["Yes"],"download_date_range":["20161201","20161215"],"first_login_date_range":[],"last_login_date_range":[],"login_frequency":[]}'
```

I want to print individual value's using PHP for example:

```
$download = 'Yes';
$country  = "Hong Kong";
```

Comment: https://eval.in/725143   . Now echo `$array['download'][0]; ..... so on for others`

Comment: @Haj Mohamed A see the answer that you want.

Comment: @HikmatSijapati I reformatted the question, not the question in itself. I'm still reading: *I want echo individual value's*

Comment: see edited answer.

Comment: see the answer @Haj Mohammad A

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = '{"promoter_name":[],"country":["Hong Kong"],"download":["Yes"],"download_date_range":["20161201","20161215"],"first_login_date_range":[],"last_login_date_range":[],"login_frequency":[]}';

$arr = json_decode($result,true);
$country = $arr['country'][0];
$download = $arr['download'][0];
```

This is array method . If you using object method code will be like this;

```
$arr = json_decode($result);
$country = $arr->country[0];
$download = $arr->download[0];
```

Or you using dynamic variable

```
foreach($arr as $k=>$v){
  if($v != []){
    ${$k} = $v[0];
   }
}
echo $country;
echo $download
```

Answer (score 0):

Decode the string first as

```
$arrResult = json_decode($result, true);
```

And then use indices to access the values

Answer (score 0):

Use `json_decode` like this. `json_decode` converts your json into object then access each members using arrow operator.

```
<?php
$result = '{"promoter_name":[],"country":["Hong Kong"],"download":["Yes"],"download_date_range":["20161201","20161215"],"first_login_date_range":[],"last_login_date_range":[],"login_frequency":[]}';
$res = json_decode($result);

echo $res->country[0];//and so on

?>
```

OR

```
  <?php
$result = '{"promoter_name":[],"country":["Hong Kong"],"download":["Yes"],"download_date_range":["20161201","20161215"],"first_login_date_range":[],"last_login_date_range":[],"login_frequency":[]}';
$res = json_decode($result,true);

foreach($res as $key=>$value)
{

        foreach($value as $k=>$v){
        $data[$key] = $v;

       }
} 
extract($data);
echo $country;//outputs Hong Kong so on
?>
```

OR

```
<?php
$result = '{"promoter_name":[],"country":["Hong Kong"],"download":["Yes"],"download_date_range":["20161201","20161215"],"first_login_date_range":[],"last_login_date_range":[],"login_frequency":[]}';
$res = json_decode($result,true);

foreach($res as $key=>$value)
{

        foreach($value as $k=>$v){
        echo $key."='".$v."'<br/>";

       }
} 
?>
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
country='Hong Kong'
download='Yes'
download_date_range='20161201'
download_date_range='20161215'
```

Answer (score 0):

All of your values in the JSON string are arrays:

```
$json = '{"promoter_name":[],"country":["Hong Kong"],"download":["Yes"],"download_date_range":["20161201","20161215"],"first_login_date_range":[],"last_login_date_range":[],"login_frequency":[]}';
```

You can do the following:

```
extract(json_decode($json, true));

echo $country[0];             // Hong Kong
echo $download[0];            // Yes
echo $download_date_range[0]; // 20161201
echo $download_date_range[1]; // 20161215
```

Or you can filter out single values:

```
foreach(json_decode($json, true) as $key => $value){
  if(is_array($value) && count($value) == 1){
    $data[$key] = $value[0];
  } elseif(empty($value)) {
    $data[$key] = null;
  } else {
    $data[$key] = $value;
  }
}

extract($data);

echo $country;                // Hong Kong
echo $download;               // Yes
echo $download_date_range[0]; // 20161201
echo $download_date_range[1]; // 20161215
```